# R integration with node script using r-script

Tags: r, node.js, ubuntu, integration

I have two very simple files to test my integration setup. First the r script inside test.R:

```
print('hello')
```

Then the index.js calling that file:

```
var R = require("r-script");
var out = R("./test.R")
           .data()
           .callSync();
```

And this is what my console is telling me:

```
$ node index.js
/home/user/index.js:3
  .data()
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

Currently, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and if I run only Rscript test.R it works with no problem. Any help?

Comment: You may need to pass something to `.data`, like `.data(0)`.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? I have the same issue running the example given with the package, both sync and async version give the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my similar issue with https://github.com/joshkatz/r-script/issues/19

If you still feeling lazy to pull the git, you can directly update the source code *./node_modules/r-script/index.js* , then edit the function *init* as

```
function init(path) {
  var obj = new R(path);
  _.bindAll(obj, "data", "call", "callSync");
  return obj;
}
```

I hope you may find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ cd node_modules/r-script
 $ rm node_modules
 $ npm install underscore@1.8.3
```

in my case, downgrade underscore works