# Run R-Script from Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, npm, rscript

This is my express server structure

```
--routes
 ----index.js
 ----graph.js
--scripts
 ----test.R
--server.js
```

I am trying to call R script from graph.js file as below

```
router.get('/test',function(req,res,next){
    var R = require("r-script");
    var out = R("./scripts/test.R")
              .data()
              .callSync();   
    res.send(out);
});
```

But I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try `R("../scripts/test.R")` with an extra `.`.  I think it's calling it relative to the `graph.js`, not `server.js`.

Comment: Yes, just tried still same error.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the repo itself.  Take a look at [joshkatz/r-script#19](https://github.com/joshkatz/r-script/issues/19).  You may need to install that particular pull request in order to deal with the issue until it is merged.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093298/r-integration-with-node-script-using-r-script

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is being called relative to `graph.js` instead of `server.js`.

Try using `R("../scripts/test.R")` with an extra `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem each time I install "r-script" but I found the solution a long time ago just there: https://github.com/joshkatz/r-script/pull/20/commits/1eb0c33628360957f0dd589b92e804fba15891d5.

Just replace `return _.bindAll(obj, "data", "call", "callSync");` by:

```
  _.bindAll(obj, "data", "call", "callSync");
  return obj;
```

in the file: `node_modules/r-script/index.js`

Hope I helped you even if you asked more than 5 months ago.